# mac yosemite how to find the "\" charector in Yosemite 10.10 version

Tags: macos, swift, keyboard, special-characters, osx-yosemite

I am using Yosemite 10.10 on vmware. i am using my dell keyboard (standard us keyboard)

when I write `\` in order to use it in `swift`, i got this strange charector, which is before the `()`:

[image]

Comment: For the record, the stange character is a [section sign `§`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

LaunchPad -> System Preference -> Keyboard -> Input Sources

From here you can change your keyboard layout so you can use "\".  Use the plus button to add the correct layout and then remove the old one, hope this helps.

Comment: when I opened that window, i can see the `\`, but it is located on the enter button, my enter button locate three buttons, i should have located just two. what should I do please?

Comment: You could restarting the whole process, disconnect the keyboard and reconnect the Mac keyboard if you have one.  Then start the process again.